# Vertical line in chart is affecting x-axis

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure out how to add a vertical line to a chart that I have created without affecting the initial data using VBA.  The initial x-y scatter with data plots fine.  When I add a vertical line, the x-axis labels all turn to 0:00:00 and most of the data is not visible.  Here's the script to create the first chart:

```
With ChtSheet 
 .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
 .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "TPart1"

    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FirstOrderNoData.Row, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastOrderNoData.Row, 1))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FirstOrderNoData.Row, PartTemp1Col.Column), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastOrderNoData.Row, PartTemp1Col.Column))

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "TPart2"

    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FirstOrderNoData.Row, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastOrderNoData.Row, 1))
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FirstOrderNoData.Row, PartTemp2Col.Column), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastOrderNoData.Row, PartTemp2Col.Column))
.ChartType = xlXYScatter
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
End With
```

which produces this chart:
[Good Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GrYv.png)

But when I later perform this:

```
With ChtSheet.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()

            .AxisGroup = 2
            .Name = "Today"
            .XValues = Array(StartTime, StartTime)
            .Values = Array(0, PartTemp1Max)
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter


            End With
```

the chart changes to this:
[Bad chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXRgB.png)

Ive tried adding a second y axis and plotting the "today"seris on it, but same thing.  Can anyone help me plot this vertical line without messing up the x-axis?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't really do charts, but is this right? `.XValues = Array(StartTime, StartTime)`.

Comment: I've seen the `.XValues = Array(StartTime, StartTime)` used in other examples of plotting vertical lines in charts, so I can only assume it works.  But when I step through the code, it is that line that changes the x-axis and data view of the chart, and it never recovers.

Comment: Look at your x-axis though - it's 0 all the way along. Anyway, I'll leave it now to someone who knows about charts.

Comment: What is `StartTime`? How is it declared, what value is assigned to it?

Comment: I don't think it matters here, but I generally list the properties of NewSeries in this order: .ChartType, .Values, .XValues, .Name, .AxisGroup (sometimes I might put .ChartType after .Name instead of up front).

Comment: StartTime is a date type.   I’ve tried it in full date format and in hh:mm:ss format and it has the same effect both ways.  The original data set also uses date type on the x-axis

Comment: @JonPeltier I used your recommended order and I get the same result.  However, I notice as I step through the script that the x-axis change happens on the .Values line, which, with your order, comes before .XValues.  This leads me to believe that the problem is with using an Array as my values, since the chart does the same thing no matter which of these lines is first.

Comment: Does it behave if the new X values (dates) are placed in the worksheet?

Comment: Yes - so what Ive noticed is that if I go back to the chart after the vertical line has been added, select the data, and edit the series, the format is not showing as hh:mm:ss.  once I change the format manually, it corrects the chart.  So what Ive attempted to do is first format StartTime before assigning it to the array, but it doesnt seem to be formatting properly using `StartTime2 = Format(StartTime, "hh:nn:ss")`.  A MsgBox still shows StartTime2 as 6:31:12 PM.  Ive also tried "hh:mm:ss".  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong with the formatting?

Comment: Okay, I found a bit of a workaround by using the cell reference that the variable StartTime came from.  Its as if since the original chart used ranges as the initial data set, it will only plot added series if they are also specified by range, not by variables.  Even though the variable I was using is the same Date data type (I checked the sheet's column data type to make sure) it messes up the chart if I don't reference it by range.  I'm not sure what is going on here, but I at least got it to plot correctly.